# resizable and draggable div with fixed surface area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Is it possible to make a resizable and draggable div with a fixed surface area?

Example: I have a square div with a surface area of 10000px² (100 x 100px) and then I change the width (with the mouse on the corner or on the edge) to 50px, the heigth should now change automaticly to 200px so the surface area stays 10000px².

Then I´d like to drag it all over the page, resize it again etc...

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Draggable - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" 

href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-

ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-

ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #draggable { width: 100px; height: 100px; padding: 0.5em; border: 

1px solid;}
  </style>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable().resizable();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

ok, so here is the code, I have resizable and draggable div but now I need the fixed surface area (eg 10000px²) as I mentioned before...

Comment: you dont have any code?

Comment: post some html or css code...otherwise it is really hard to help you ;)

Comment: I found this http://jqueryui.com/draggable/ http://jqueryui.com/resizable/ and I can use it but I dont know how to specify the fixed surface area part.. I dont have any code, I am gona write it when I find out how to do it...

Comment: Your code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/CesnY/

Comment: @APAD1 ... apart from the area remaining the same!

Comment: I know, but now I need this: When I change the width to 50px, the heigth should change automaticly to 200px so the surface area stays 10000px².

Comment: Perhaps something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/CesnY/2/ it isn't very smooth but you should be able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery's UI to do all of this.

use http://jqueryui.com/draggable/ to allow for dragging,
use http://jqueryui.com/resizable/ to allow for resizing

using the [resize event](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#event-resize), you can have jquery modify the div so it will follow any height/width rules you want.

Comment: i think you should do an example with some code. it is better

Comment: Can you give me please an example of that rules I need?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(function(draggable) {
    var elm = document.getElementById(draggable);
    elm.onmousedown = drag;

    function stop() {
        document.onmouseup   = null;
        document.onmousemove = null;
    }

    function drag(e) {
        if (e.target == elm) {
            var absX    = e.clientX;
            var absY    = e.clientY;
            var left    = parseInt(getComputedStyle(elm).left, 10);
            var top     = parseInt(getComputedStyle(elm).top, 10);
            var relX    = absX - left;
            var relY    = absY - top;

            document.onmouseup   = stop;
            document.onmousemove = function(e) {
                var absX    = e.clientX;
                var absY    = e.clientY;
                elm.style.left  = absX - relX  + "px";
                elm.style.top   = absY - relY  + "px";
            }
        }
    }
})("box");


(function(resizeable) {
    var elm     = document.getElementById(resizeable);
    var wHandler    = elm.childNodes[1];
    var hHandler    = elm.childNodes[3];
    wHandler.onmousedown    = resizeW;
    hHandler.onmousedown    = resizeH;

    function stop() {
        elm.style.cursor = "";
        document.body.style.cursor = "";
        document.onmouseup   = null;
        document.onmousemove = null;
    }

    var w       = 100;
    var h       = 100;
    var area    = w * h;

    function resizeW(e) {
        elm.style.cursor = "w-resize";
        document.body.style.cursor = "w-resize";
        var left    = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(elm, null)["left"], 10);

        document.onmouseup   = stop;
        document.onmousemove = function(e) {
            var absX    = e.clientX;
            var width   = absX - left;
            var height  = area / width;
            elm.style.width     = width + "px";
            elm.style.height    = height + "px";
        }
    }

    function resizeH(e) {
        elm.style.cursor = "n-resize";
        document.body.style.cursor = "n-resize";
        var top     = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(elm, null)["top"], 10);

        document.onmouseup   = stop;
        document.onmousemove = function(e) {
            var absY    = e.clientY;
            var height  = absY - top;
            var width   = area / height;
            elm.style.height    = height + "px";
            elm.style.width     = width + "px";
        }
    }
})("box");
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/akinuri/f86TS/)

Though there's a small bug, I think. Couldn't fix it. When you resize the width it's ok, but when you resize the height, and then move the div, it lags or w/e. Check the fiddle. Other than this, it's working fine.

Comment: Yes, there´s a small bug but It gives the trick. But the handlers are over the box size, arent they? So the box width and height is smaller by 3px I think?...

Comment: No. The box is exactly 100x100px. Handlers are inside the box, and positioned `absolutely`. They don't affect the box. You can change their appearance.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I put them (opticaly) outside the box and now It´s fine, thanks for help :)